# Error while fetching 100K records from mongodb in Scala using Akk-Http

Tags: mongodb, scala, akka-http

I've written following code to fetch records and perform action

On akka-http route,

```
complete(mongoDB.getCollection(getCollectionName(user_id, list_id)).find()
    .getAllContacts(user_id, list_id).map { line =>
        validateNumber(line.phone, prefixTrim)
    }.toFuture().map(_.size.toString))
```

On testing the API with wrk with 1000 connection and 10 threads, I'm getting following errors

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
 Error during processing of request: 'Boxed Error'. 
Completing with 500 Internal Server Error response. 
To change default exception handling behavior, provide a custom ExceptionHandler.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Boxed Error

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Is there anyway to resolve this issue without increasing heap size?

UPDATED

The collection size = 33MB
and

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'heapsize|permsize|threadstacksize'
     intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0                                   {pd product}
    uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0                                   {product}
    uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520                            {product}
    uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 268435456                           {product}
    uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728                           {product}
    uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 4294967296                          {product}
     intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024                                {pd product}
     intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 1024                                {pd product}
java version "1.8.0_131"
```

Comment: How big is this collection you're loading? Does mongo bring it all to memory at once? What is the configuration value you've set for max JVM memory? (the `-Xmx` flag)?

Comment: I've updated my question. Seems all data are loaded on memory at once

Comment: you don'T have enough memory to your java app to hold 100K records. You can increase it using the java -Xmx flag, or finding an approach that does not hold all data into memory, for instance by streaming

Answer (score 2):

If your heap cannot hold all the data you will need to stream the result as you get it:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/source-streaming-support.html